# Why am I seeing iAd's advertisements, like I did in development, in my production app?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, iad

My app just got submitted to the app store and I just downloaded it, I am getting iAd's advertisements just like while I was developing it.  Will is this showing up on other peoples devices?  Or just on the devices that I have in my developer account?

Comment: I have the same issue ...  with iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you've got a development version on the phone and that wasn't overwritten by your app downloaded from app store.

So, just try deleting the app from your phone and computer, and then try to re-sync.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you will not see your iAd ads on a device where you have installed any provisioning profiles.

In any case, to make sure that everything is working correctly, you should go to: http://iad.apple.com, log in, and check the status of your app (i.e., click on the app name at the bottom of the Summary page where you land).

If everything is ok, you should see a status message like in the attached picture. If not, the status message will mention "test ads". In this case, get in touch with Apple by going to itunesconnect and clicking the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page. They will fix it quickly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks sergio, I was just wondering how others know how many ads their apps serve, ctr etc.  Thanks!  I would have never known!

Comment: Another side note, do you know whether or not an iPhone only app will serve ads if an iPad user downloads it?  Assuming it's connected to wifi or data of course.